# Snapdragon Neural Processing Engine Installation

Tags: python, pip, ubuntu-18.04, qualcomm

I'm running source check_python_depends.sh as part of  Qualcomm's Sanpdragon Neural Processing Engine SDK. As part of the installation process I run the following command

source check_python_depends.sh

> Checking for python-yaml: install ok installed
>   WARNING: It appears the python module pyyaml is installed on this system using the apt-get distribution as well as pip. If you encounter errors, please use only one distribution.

When I run apt-get remove pyyaml I receive the following

> E: Unable to locate package pyyaml

Is there another name I should be looking for in Ubuntu?

Similiarly I receive the following messages during installation suggesting they aren't in pip or installed via the global package management.

1. dpkg-query: no packages found matching python-protobuf
2. dpkg-query: no packages found matching python-sphinx

Are the naming conventions between Ubuntu and PIP not harmonized creating so much ambiguity? Am I correct to assume if there is not a global requirement that I'm generally better off using a local pip installation?

Answer (score 1):

> `apt-get remove pyyaml`

In Debian/Ubuntu the package is called `python-yaml` or `python3-yaml`:

```
apt-get remove python{,3}-yaml
```

> dpkg-query: no packages found

That probably means they're installed using `pip` and not `apt`.

> Are the naming conventions between Ubuntu and PIP not harmonized

Of course no. Debian and `pip` development are completely independent. `pip` install packages from [PyPI](https://pypi.org/) where developers of individual packages give names for their packages. Debian developers rename the packages to suite their own needs; to separate python2- and python3-installable packages, e.g.